# Replace embedded views with multiple data sources

Tags: xpages

I am building an application that will have a parent documents with up to 5 different child documents attached to the parent. Each parent can have one and only 1 of each of the 5 types of child documents.

In traditional notes programming I would probably put an embedded view within the parent documents form. I was starting down that path when I wondered if this wouldn't be better done in Xpages with one Xpage that has multiple datasources.

A complicating factor is that each form/data source will have a different group of people who own it - only they can create or edit it. But I don't think this would be a problem.

Comment: What's your specific question, Bryan?

Comment: Yes, ill formed questioned. Should have been, do multiple data sources on a page replace the need for embedded views. I think the answer is yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of ideas to consider ...

- don't use response docs ... tie the related docs together via a document key like unid
- put the create/edit function for the five child docs in their own separate panels ... childpanel1, childpanel2, etc.
- add the datasources for the child docs in the respective panels ... childdoc1, childdoc2, etc
- restrict edit access via the acl property for each panel
- with multiple data sources on an XPage remember to set ignoreRequestParams="true" for the childdoc data sources

For example, here's the panel structure for the first child doc:

```
    <xp:panel id="childpanel1">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="childdoc1" formName="ChildForm1"
            ignoreRequestParams="true">
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:this.acl>
        <xp:acl>
            <xp:this.entries>
                <xp:aclEntry type="GROUP" name="doc1group" right="EDITOR">
                </xp:aclEntry>
            </xp:this.entries>
        </xp:acl>
    </xp:this.acl>
</xp:panel>
```

**More on ignoreRequestParams:**

In a two-page application involving a "view" XPage and a "document" XPage, when the application user clicks a link on the view page to open the document on the document page the ID for the document to open is passed with the REQUEST parameters.  You can see this in the resulting URL for the document page which will have the ID for the document to open appended to the URL address, for example:

```
&documentId=49530CA58D17CCE5852575150069D857&action=openDocument
```

This works perfectly when the document page has only one Domino document data source.  However, in the embedded view application the "document" XPage will also include a data source for the xp:viewPanel.  When ignoreRequestParams is NOT true for the Domino view data source (and for any other additional data sources on the page, like childdoc1) then the parameters passed in the request ARE evaluated to determine which view entries to display in the xp:viewPasnel.  These request parameters point to a UNID that is not the desired data source for the view so no view entries are displayed.

Note, you may not need to set ignoreRequestParams to true for ALL of the data sources on the XPage ... just be aware of this setting and what it does when things get wonky for one of the view or document data sources on the page.

Comment: Paul, these are all good ideas, and the way I think I want to go. In essence you do not need to use embedded views anymore. I will probably put each panel in a custom control, and I will have a form for each child doc. One question, why set ignoreRequestParams="true"?

Comment: Paul, I also don't use response docs. I find that joining the documents together with a UNID gives me some flexibility. Would you mind explaining why you don't use response docs?

Comment: Unless they are already part of an existing application I never use response docs for my XPages applications ... I find they can complicate things.  I tend to go for a more normalized doc/data structure for any new XPages development.

Comment: I NEVER have used response document in xpages.  It just doesn't make sense to me because now in xpages you can easily break out related documents into different .nsf files if needed.  I always relate documents with the old fashioned @Unique. In Java that looks like this:  String.valueOf(session.evaluate("@Unique").get(0));

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your question is how to limit the form creation or how to have something like an embedded view in xPages. Both are easier to do in xPages.

Basically you just need to make the children responses of the parent. I prefer to not use normal response documents and prefer instead to add a field called uid with the unid of the parent to the children. I then filter my datasource to match the uid of the parent document. You can use view controls for this but repeats look even better.

Its a great place to start using dialogs as you can have the second data source in the dialog and the user never needs to leave the page.

As far as restricting the view creation you can do something like hide the button to create a new child based on a criteria.

This action will add the unid of document1 to document3

```
<xp:modifyField name="uid"
    value="#{javascript:document1.getDocument().getUniversalID()}"  var="document3">
</xp:modifyField>
```

Here is the code I use for a repeat control datasource. The view is categorized by uid field

```
<xp:dominoView var="view7" viewName="VIEWNAME"
        keys="#{javascript:document1.getDocument().getUniversalID()}">
    </xp:dominoView>
```

Then the repeat control just grabs the fields you want.

```
<xp:table styleClass="table">
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td>Column Header</xp:td>
                    <xp:td>Column Header</xp:td>
                    <xp:td>Column Header</xp:td>
                </xp:tr>

                <xp:repeat id="repeat3" rows="30" value="#{view7}"
                    var="rowData">
                    <xp:tr>
                        <xp:td>
                            <xp:text escape="true"
                                id="computedField3" value="#{rowData.columnname1}">
                            </xp:text>
                        </xp:td>
                        <xp:td>
                            <xp:text escape="true"
                                id="computedField4" value="#{rowData.columnname2}">
                            </xp:text>
                        </xp:td>
                        <xp:td>
                            <xp:text escape="true"
                                id="computedField5" value="#{rowData.columnname3}">
                            </xp:text>
                        </xp:td>
                    </xp:tr>
                </xp:repeat>
            </xp:table>
```

Ignore some of the styleclasses as I am using bootstrap.

Comment: This is some good code, I especially appreciate the unit code.